# Is app localization implemented at download time or runtime?

Tags: android, ios, localization

For iOS and Android apps that are designed with regional/language localization, I want to know: Are all of the different localized strings, etc. downloaded onto the user's device when purchasing from the app store, or is it already optimized for file size, by only downloading those that match the user's regional/language settings at the time of purchase?

If it's the former (everything is downloaded onto the device and then the localization is implemented at runtime), then that will be a big problem for me. My app relies on a very large database of text, which needs to be in the user device's language. Having all of the different language versions at the same time will take up a ton of space. So, that means either I have to: 1) have a monster app file size, or 2) have to release a different instance of the app in each language, neither of which is ideal (though I can live with the second option if I have to). Or is there some other way?

Even though I'm still a long way from release I need to start thinking about this because it will affect the way I organize things going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it in your app, so i don't think that app thining process takes care of that.

If you have a large base of texts you should consider creating a service for it and fetch texts from that service when needed, based on your device language or a user preference (language menu) if you have it in the app.